# My program has a Java. Net. Socketexception: connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient

I use httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);  Ten seconds later, I executed ExecuteMethod (postmethod) again and got socketexception: connection reset.“postmethod” is the same object。
I want to know what happened, do they use the same socket connection? Did the server close the socket connection due to the long waiting time?n, and the connection reset exception occurred.

Httpclient is org. Apache. Commons. Httpclient. Httpclient. Httpclient

Thanks for your help！

Answer (score 0):

> Which HTTP version protocol is your host using?

[image]

Maybe you need to use a keep-alive header.

[See more details on from.](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/http-keep-alive/)

Comment: Thank you, but I wonder if the connection I first established will be closed after I finish my first request and get the response normally? Shouldn't the second request after ten seconds reestablish the connection?